# triggers that works for Oracle and I’m trying to produce the MySQL equivalent

Tags: mysql, oracle

I’ve got a really simple MySQL trigger that I can’t get to work

```sql
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER RECORD_TRIGGER
BEFORE  INSERT 
ON RECORD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.MARK < 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = ‘The mark cannot be negative';
    END IF;

END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: You are using the wrong quote marks. The syntax highlighting in the question is a clue. You should use a text editor (or IDE) which supports syntax highlighting, so you can get such feedback immediately, rather than posting here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A typo (wrong quote chars).

```
CREATE TRIGGER RECORD_TRIGGER
BEFORE  INSERT 
ON RECORD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.MARK < 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The mark cannot be negative';
    END IF;
    IF NEW.MARK > 100 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'The mark cannot exceed 100.'; 
    END IF;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8377ed0261154912698d7ab41a68e46e)

Comment: @EA90 Both opening quotes in both `SET MESSAGE_TEXT = ‘message text';` statements.